# How to include one line above of the keyword line during SPLITING a big txt file using Regex and PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

We have got a big txt file ("C:\temp\longmessages.txt") like below:

Americas

This is Start

some text 1

some text 2

some text 3

etc. etc

End

Europe

This is Start

some text 4

some text 5

some text 6

some text 7

etc. etc

End

Asia

This is Start

some text 8

some text 9

some text 10

etc. etc

End

By using the below PS script, I am able to **SPLIT** **"C:\temp\longmessages.txt"** into **smaller 1.txt, 2.txt, 3.txt** etc. each smaller .txt file **split from first "Start" to next "Start"** however each smaller file begins from "Start" and leaving the line above the **"This is Start"** while **we want to include one line above the "Start" on the top of each smaller split file means Americas, Europe** etc. **needs to be added to each file above the "Start"**

```
$InputFile = "C:\temp\longmessages.txt"
$Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)
$a = 1
While (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    **If ($Line -match "START")** {
  
       $OutputFile = "C:\temp\output\$a.txt"
       $filename
  if ($filename -eq $null){
  
  $OutputFile = $filename
  }
       
        $a++
    }
     
     
    Add-Content $OutputFile $Line
  
}
```

Comment: Then why not split at `"END"` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment, I think it would be far easier to make the split on the line that says `End`.

Try

```
$path  = 'C:\temp\longmessages.txt'
# create a List object to add lines to
$lines = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
$count = 1

# use 'switch' to parse the log file line-by-line
switch -Regex -File $path {
    '^End$' { 
        # add 'End' to the list
        $lines.Add($_)
        # if the top line is empty or whitespace only, remove that line
        if ([string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($lines[0])) { $lines.RemoveAt(0) }
        # create the full name of the output file and increment the file counter
        $OutputFile = 'C:\temp\output\{0}.txt' -f $count++
        # write the file
        $lines | Set-Content -Path $OutputFile -Force
        # clear the list for the next file
        $lines.Clear()
    }
    default { $lines.Add($_) }
}
```

Using your example this results in three files:

**1.txt**

```
Americas

This is Start

some text 1

some text 2

some text 3

etc. etc

End
```

**2.txt**

```
Europe

This is Start

some text 4

some text 5

some text 6

some text 7

etc. etc

End
```

**3.txt**

```
Asia

This is Start

some text 8

some text 9

some text 10

etc. etc

End
```